# How to display data in Angular without ngOnInit()?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a cigarette counter app in Ionic 4. Stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-8xrdgo. I need to display the up-to-date consumption data in the history segment when user presses on the Add One button in the counter segment. For some reason, an app reload is required for the up-to-date data to be displayed in the history segment.

To reproduce the problem:

1. Start the app without `consumption` in the Storage
2. Click the Add One button. A new consumption is added to storage successfully.
3. Click the Add One button again. The existing consumption should be updated now, but for some reason it is not. Also, the history segment does not display the data.
4. Reload the app.
5. Click the Add One button. Now the existing consumption is successfully updated to the storage and the consumption is displayed in the history segment.

The problem here is that reloading the app is necessary in order to update the existing consumption to the storage and display it.

Full code here:

home.page.html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="segment" color="dark">
      <ion-segment-button value="info">
        Info
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="counter">
        Counter
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="history">
        History
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

  <div *ngIf="segment == 'info'">
    <h1 class="center">Cigarette pack info</h1>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input placeholder="Price" type="number" [(ngModel)]="pack.price"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input placeholder="Cigarette count" type="number" [(ngModel)]="pack.cigarettecount"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <br>
    <ion-button expand="block" color="dark" (click)="savePack()">Save</ion-button>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="segment == 'counter'">
    <h1 class="center">Consumption today</h1>
    <p class="center">{{ today.date }}</p>
    <p class="center">{{ today.consumption }}</p>
    <p class="center">{{ today.last_smoked }}</p>
    <ion-button expand="block" color="dark" (click)="addOne()">Add one</ion-button>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="segment == 'history'">
    <h1 class="center">Recent consumption</h1>
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col><b>Date</b></ion-col>
        <ion-col><b>Consumption</b></ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row *ngFor="let history of histories">
        <ion-col>{{ history.date }}</ion-col>
        <ion-col>{{ history.consumption }}</ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>-{{ money_consumption_tostring  }} €</ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </div>

</ion-content>
```

interfaces:

```
export interface pack {
    price: number,
    cigarettecount: number
}

export interface consumption {
    date: string,
    consumption: number,
    last_smoked: string
}
```

home.page.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { pack } from '../pack.interface';
import { consumption } from '../consumption.interface';
import { ConsumptionService } from '../consumption.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(private service: ConsumptionService) { }

  segment: string = "info";
  pack: pack[] = [];
  today = {} as consumption;
  histories: consumption[] = [];
  price: number = 0;
  money_consumption: number = 0;
  money_consumption_tostring: string = "0";

  ngOnInit() {

    this.service.getConsumptions().then((data: consumption[]) => {
      if (data == null) {
        this.today.consumption = 0;
        this.today.date = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
        this.today.last_smoked = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
      } else {
        for (let consumption of data) {
          if (consumption.date == new Date().toLocaleDateString()) {
            this.today = consumption;
          }
        }
      }

      this.service.getConsumptions().then((data: consumption[]) => {
        this.histories = data;
      })
    })

    this.service.getPack().then((data) => {
      if (data != null) {
        this.segment = "counter";
      }
    })

  }

  addOne = () => {
    this.today.date = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
    this.today.consumption += 1;
    this.today.last_smoked = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();

    this.service.getConsumptions().then((data: consumption[]) => {
      let consumptions = data;
      // at least one consumption found
      if (consumptions != null) {
        let current_exists = false;
        for (let consumption of consumptions) {
          // use current date
          if (consumption.date == this.today.date) {
            current_exists = true;
            consumption.date = this.today.date;
            consumption.consumption = this.today.consumption;
            consumption.last_smoked = this.today.last_smoked;

            // add current consumption to history
            for (let history of this.histories) {
              if (history.date == this.today.date) {
                history.date = this.today.date;
                history.consumption = this.today.consumption;
                history.last_smoked = this.today.last_smoked;
              }
            }

          }
        }
        // new date
        if (current_exists == false) {
          consumptions.push(this.today);
          this.histories.push(this.today);
        }
        this.service.saveConsumptions(consumptions);
      } else {
        // no consumptions found
        this.service.addConsumptions(this.today);
        this.histories = data;
      }
    })
  }

  savePack = () => {
    this.service.savePack(this.pack);
    this.segment = "counter";
  }

}
```

consumption.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { pack } from './pack.interface';
import { consumption } from './consumption.interface';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConsumptionService {

  constructor(private storage: Storage) { }

  getPack = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.storage.get("pack").then((pack) => {
        resolve(pack);
      })
    })
  }

  savePack = (pack: pack[]) => {
    this.storage.set("pack", pack);
  }

  getConsumptions = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.storage.get("consumption").then((kulutukset) => {
        resolve(kulutukset);
      })
    })
  }

  addConsumptions = (newconsumption: consumption) => {
    this.storage.get("consumption").then((data: consumption[]) => {
      let consumptions = data;
      let current_exists = false;
      if (consumptions == null) {
        consumptions = [{date: new Date().toLocaleDateString(), 
          consumption: 0, last_smoked: new Date().toLocaleTimeString()},
        ]
      }
      for (let consumption of consumptions) {
        // use current date
        if (consumption.date == newconsumption.date) {
          current_exists = true;
          consumption.date = newconsumption.date;
          consumption.consumption = newconsumption.consumption;
          consumption.last_smoked = newconsumption.last_smoked;
        }
      }
      // new date
      if (current_exists == false) {
        consumptions.push(newconsumption);
      }
      this.storage.set("consumption", consumptions);
    }
    )}

    saveConsumptions = (consumptions: consumption[]) => {
      this.storage.set("consumption", consumptions);
    }

}
```

Comment: please create a stackbliz

Comment: Stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-8xrdgo Please also try to fix the StaticInjectError error for me.

Answer (score 3):

It's important to understand how the lifecycle of a page/component works in Ionic;

- constructor is called before the initialisation of everything else, as soon as the component is placed;
- ngOnInit (OnInit Angular event) is called **ONCE** when the component/page is being loaded
- there are a bunch of Ionic lifecycles coming out of the box for any Ionic application as "ionViewDidLoad", "ionViewWillLoad" etc, which have all kind of different behaviours, which might actually suit your needs

As Ionic app actually stacks one page on top of the other in order to match the mobile app's standard behaviours with the back buttons and all (check the application's structure in browser devtools and try opening multiple pages), the correct way would be to hang on the Ionic lifecycles, as **ionViewDidLoad** or **ionViewWillLoad**; this event is triggered every time the view is loaded, app being re-opened or page being navigated to.

Read more here: https://blog.ionicframework.com/navigating-lifecycle-events/

Answer (score 1):

You can do in the constructor(){ }

```
data = [];
constructor(private storage: Storage) { 
  //write your code
  //for example:
  this.storage.get("pack").then((pack) => {
    this.data = pack;
  })
}
```